# Load multiple jquery version in the same project but not the same pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, version

I'm working on updating an aspx project to asp net MVC. As the work is in progress, half of the pages are still in apsx. For my aspx pages, I need to have jquery-1-x-x loaded, and for my asp net pages, jquery-3-x-x (I use some jquery-3 functionalities on my mvc pages, but using this version on my aspx pages provokes error I didn't manage to deal with).

To do so, I have jquery-1 loaded in my Portail_MasterPage

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" />
```

To add jquery-3 in my asp net pages, I used bundles. I have this in my BundleConfig.cs :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"));
```

And then I use a layout file which has this line :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and which is called in each html file (asp net pages) :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "SaisieConges";
Layout = "~/Areas/MVC/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
```

With this, I have jquery-1-x-x loaded in my aspx pages, and jquery-1-x-x + jquery-3-x-x loaded in my asp net pages. But I recently found out that having both jquery versions loaded in the same page provokes issues.

So, what I want to know is if there is a way to load only one specific jquery version depending on if I am on aspx page or not.

Thank you for your time, and sorry for my english !

Comment: I did something similar with an ASP project, but I conditionally loaded CSS files depending on what webpage I was on (with a case/switch).

I'm sure you could do something similar with jQuery.

Comment: Why/How do you have both loaded in MVC?  They should be using different masterpage / _layout and your description indicates that the layout has *only* 3.5 - so how did tit get 1.10?  Did you add the `<asp:ScriptReference` to your *MVC* page?  Don't.

Comment: Where did you write this statement ? I'm not sure if I can efficiently use my page extension as a condition for loading a specific version :/

Comment: I think MVC is using the same masterpage, so it loads jquery-1 version on my mvc pages too. I confirm that my layout has only 3.5, so i suppose that 1.10 comes from the masterpage as it is the only place on my project where it is specified

Comment: Then you should fix **that problem** rather than its effect

Comment: I tried to change my asp:ScriptReference  to jquery-3, and I can confirm that now only jquery-3 is loaded on my mvc pages, but in my aspx pages too.

Comment: Why is this a problem (i'm not very familiar with this :/) ? I need users to access to some of the old pages and some of the new ones, as I update them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted, keeping a global master page for he whole project (aspx + aspnet), but I had to modify every of my aspx files (it doesn't matter as I plan to delete them once updated).

I have put my Script reference inside a ContentPlaceHolder like this :

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ScriptManager" runat="server">

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager0" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" CombineScripts="false" ScriptMode="Release">
        <Scripts>
            ...
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js" />
            ...
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Thanks to this, every files has jquery-3-5-1 by default. To override this version (instead of adding a second version), you can modify the original ContentPlaceHolder in the aspx pages you want like this :

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptManager" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager0" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" CombineScripts="false" ScriptMode="Release">
            <Scripts>
                ...
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" />
        ...
            </Scripts>
     </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
</asp:Content>
```

With this, I'm able to load only the desired jquery version.